# Angular md-virtual-repeat is not updating changed data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I'm using angular **md-virtual-repeat** to load listings in my container and its working fine as the listings are not being changed. When i update the listings on specific event id's, the **$scope.listings** get updated correctly but the listings don't change in view. And when i do scrolling, they get updated.

It seems like it doesn't get the trigger of data change. Is there any solution to refresh **md-virtual-repeat** when data updates ?

```
<div id="listingsScrollArea" md-virtual-repeat-container>
   <table>
      <tbody id="listings_body">
        <tr md-virtual-repeat="listing in listings | listingsSort:sortType:sortReverse:searchFields:filterListingsBy:false" class="repeated-item" ng-click="dosomething(listing)">
            <td ng-if="listing.isListing">{{ ::listing.x }}</td>
            ...
            <td ng-if="listing.isListing">{{ ::listing.y }}</td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

ListingsController method to get listings. Listings get updated by re-runing this method.

```
$scope.getListings = function(event_ids, pageNo) {
   var deferred = $q.defer();
   $scope.isListingsLoading = true;

   ListingsFactory.getListings(event_ids, pageNo).then(function(data) {
      $scope.listings = data.data;
      $scope.listings_info = data.info;
      $scope.isListingsLoading = false;
      deferred.resolve(data);
   }, function(data) {
      deferred.reject(data);
   });

   return deferred.promise;
};
```

Comment: so how do you update listings? Do u rerun getListings function?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're using one-time binding. That does not mix well with md-virtual-repeat. Try changing this:

`<td ng-if="listing.isListing">{{ ::listing.x }}</td>`

into this:

`<td ng-if="listing.isListing">{{ listing.x }}</td>`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
$scope.getListings = function(event_ids, pageNo) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $scope.isListingsLoading = true;

    ListingsFactory.getListings(event_ids, pageNo).then(function(data) {
        deferred.resolve(data);
    }, function(data) {
        deferred.reject(data);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
};

$scope.getListings.then(function(data) {
    $scope.listings = data.data;
    $scope.listings_info = data.info;
    $scope.isListingsLoading = false;
});
```

Comment: It didn't work. Can you please explain more whats the difference? and how should it work?